# Why am I unable to place one div below the other div?

Tags: html, css

I know this sounds too simple but I am unable to place one `div` below the other `div` , and my code is

html:

```
<div id="gamediv"></div>
<div class="style"></div>
```

css:

```
.style {
    width:728px;
    height:90px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: This is all of your code?

Comment: you should give us more info, i really can't get your problem man.

Comment: do you need like this http://jsfiddle.net/oezpz74s/

Comment: .style is aligned below #gamediv only. What exactly is your issue.

Comment: it looks like its working http://jsfiddle.net/8uLuqzv6/10/

Comment: If you want to see where exactly the divs are aligned apply height and background color to both the divs. You can it is aligned one by one.

Comment: share expected output as image representation?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4og9d5xp/

Comment: i am using internet explorer 11

Answer (score 0):

After doing some ugly hack in my `css` & in my first `div style` i am able to place my desired `div` below first `div` , this is my `css` code:

```
.style{
    width:728px;
    height:90px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:323px;
}
```

first `div style` property: `<div id="gamediv" style="position:relative;"></div>`

for now this solution is working but still i can't figure out why previous solutions didn't worked, any explanation regarding this is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuses your div will be displayed befault in line.
It will take all the space it has to dispay divs.
 something you can do is to create another div to include the 2 you create and specifying a specific width:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="gamediv"></div>
    <div class="style"></div>
</div>
```

Then add your style such as

```
#container{
width: 800px;
height: 200px;
}
.gamediv{
width:750px;
height:40px;
}
.style {
width:728px;
height:90px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

then you may want to align with float or centre with margin:auto; Try to to imagine div as boxes. if it help you may add

```
border:1px solid black;
```

this will draw the box and you will see what you are doing

Answer (score -1):

add display: block; also in the stylesheet (for both div)

Comment: Not required if that's all the code he have as `div` is a block level element by default

Comment: divs are natively `display: block;`